# What do you call a ブザービーター　in baseball?

Tags: words, sports

Is it possible to have something similar to a buzzer beater in baseball? What is it called in Japanese? If not, how would you refer to a game-winning action in a sport?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're referring to.  I've never heard of anything like "buzzer beater" in English, let alone Japanese.  Neither am I sure what you're referring by a "game-winning" action.  Are you referring to something like a "hail Mary" pass?  If you won a game, does that mean there was a "game-winning" action?

Comment: You ask what it's called in Japanese, but then in your title you wrote ブザービーター, which I found in Denshi Jisho. Is that a term you found in Japanese?  Perhaps I'm just ignorant about these things.  But regardless, your question seems a bit circular in that you're asking for a Japanese term, but then you provide what would seem to be the answer to your question.

Comment: Presumably "buzzer beater" means scoring right before/as the timer expires.  But baseball does not have a timer.  So.....

Comment: @A.Ellett Perhaps they just wrote the English term in katakana for some reason, even though they weren't sure if that's proper Japanese, and they're asking for proper Japanese way for the word?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean [basketball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buzzer_beater)?

Comment: @A.Ellett not a basketball fan, huh :)

Comment: @Leebo i guess so. basically, not much of a sports guy unless it involves packing a tent and heading out someplace remote into the woods. well, at least i’ve learned something here. lol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no buzzer to beat in baseball.

The closest thing I can think of is サヨナラヒット, サヨナラホームラン, etc. They refer to a play that scores a winning run in the bottom of the ninth or later inning and thus literally ends the game.

In sports commentary, [起死回生]{きしかいせい} is often used to refer to a late game-winning action. It could also be used for a game-tying action in games in which a tie is worth something, such as football. For example, an equalizer in the dying minutes of a match would be called 起死回生の同点ゴール. It is like saying an equalizing goal that brings the (otherwise-dead) team back to life.